# Using month and date together in C++

Tags: c++, date

I was trying to make a program that calculated the fee of a membership at a swimming pool. The user would enter a date (the last time a member renewed the membership), and the program would calculate if their membership was overdue or not, using the current date.

The membership is meant to be overdue a week (or another arbitrary time period) before the start of the month they joined in a year's time. For example, if I joined in February 2016, I would have to pay on January 24 2017 or before to make sure the membership is overdue. As soon as it gets to January 25, a month fee should be charged ($15) and as soon as it reaches February 25, two months fee should be charged etc.

However, I do not know how to charge for subsequent months after the first one. For example, paying on February 3 should result in one month overdue but paying on February 26 should be two months but I do not know how to do this.

How can I fix my function because it doesn't seem to work?
E.g. I entered November 15 2016 and it should return 15 since the membership was due on October 24 2017 but it returns 0.

```
int membershipFine(int joinDay, int joinMonth, int joinYear, int currentDay, int currentMonth, int currentYear)
{
    int dueDay[12] = {25, 22, 25, 24, 25, 24, 25, 25, 24, 25, 24, 25}; // the week before the end of each month in days
    int correspondingMonth = joinMonth - 2; // finds the element position that corresponds
    if (correspondingMonth == -1) // if they joined in january, the array will go to december
    {
        correspondingMonth = 11;
    }
    int differenceInMonths = currentMonth - joinMonth + 12 * (currentYear - joinYear);
    if (differenceInMonths < 11)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if ((differenceInMonths == 11) && (joinDay < dueDay[correspondingMonth]))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (differenceInMonths == 11)
    {
        return 15;
    }

    if (differenceInMonths > 11 && joinDay < dueDay[correspondingMonth]) // not sure about this if and else statement
    {
        return (differenceInMonths - 11) * 15;
    }
    else return (differenceInMonths - 10) * 15;
}
```

Comment: As a general advice try to format the code to be easy to read. Also show what the actual error or unexpected output is. It seems a part of the homework assignment to figure out the question you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with dates and times is to use a library that raises the level of abstraction about integers, to dates and times.  [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source, header-only library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) is such a tool.

It has a `{year, month, day}` class called `date::year_month_day` that lends itself to year and month arithmetic.  One could use this to change the API of `membershipFine` from taking 6 type-unsafe parameters to just two type-safe parameters:

```
int
membershipFine(date::year_month_day joinDate, date::year_month_day currentDate);
```

Your description of the due date appears to say that it is independent of the day of the month of the join date, and that it is 1 year, less 1 week from the first of the month of the join date.  If this is true, this can be easily computed like this:

```
using namespace date;
year_month_day dueDate{
    local_days{(joinDate.year()/joinDate.month() + years{1})/1} - weeks{1}};
```

The expression `joinDate.year()/joinDate.month()` creates a `year_month` object, which is just a year and month, neglecting the day-of-the-month from `joinDate`.  I add 1 year to that `year_month`, which results in another `year_month`, exactly 1 year later.

To that sum, `/1` is appended.  This creates a `year_month_day` corresponding to the first day of the month of the aforementioned `year_month`.

Now even though `year_month_day` is great for `year` and `month` oriented arithmetic, it is not so great for day and week-oriented arithmetic.  The best data structure for that is a `{count-of-days}` from some epoch.  This library has such a data structure called `local_days`.  So I convert to that, subtract 1 week, and then convert back to `year_month_day`.

All of this (to compute the due date) happens in the lines of code above.

Now I need to compute the `fine` based on the relationship between `currentDate` and `dueDate`.  The `fine` is $0 if `currentDate < dueDate`, and otherwise is a function of the number of whole months (plus 1) `currentDate` is beyond `dueDate` (as I understand your problem statement):

```
int fine = 0;
if (currentDate >= dueDate)
{
    auto differenceInMonths = currentDate.year()/currentDate.month() -
                              dueDate.year()/dueDate.month();
    if (currentDate.day() >= dueDate.day())
        ++differenceInMonths;
    fine = differenceInMonths.count() * 15;
}
```

The difference in months, neglecting the day-of-the-month, can be computed by converting to `year_month` objects and subtracting.  Now if `currentDate.day() < dueDate.day()`, this is the correct answer.  For example if the difference in months is 1, but the day of the month in `currentDate` has not yet exceeded the day of the month in `dueDate`, then we don't want to charge for a second month, else we do.  If we do, `differenceInMonths` is incremented.

Then the `fine` is simply the `differenceInMonths`, converted from `months` to integral, times 15.

`<aside>` If there are any `<chrono>` fans out there, the type of `differenceInMonths` is actually a `std::chrono::duration` with a period that is exactly the average month.  Thus the `.count()` member function to access the underlying integral value.

I've added some print statements to the above code, and below I show the whole thing put together plus a driver with a few examples:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
membershipFine(date::year_month_day joinDate, date::year_month_day currentDate)
{
    using namespace date;
    year_month_day dueDate{
        local_days{(joinDate.year()/joinDate.month() + years{1})/1} - weeks{1}};
    int fine = 0;
    if (currentDate >= dueDate)
    {
        auto differenceInMonths = currentDate.year()/currentDate.month() -
                                  dueDate.year()/dueDate.month();
        if (currentDate.day() >= dueDate.day())
            ++differenceInMonths;
        fine = differenceInMonths.count() * 15;
    }
    std::cout << "join    Date is " << joinDate << '\n';
    std::cout << "due     Date is " << dueDate << '\n';
    std::cout << "current Date is " << currentDate << '\n';
    std::cout << "fine is         $" << fine << '\n';
    return fine;
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace date::literals;
    std::cout << membershipFine(feb/29/2016, jan/24/2017) << '\n';
    std::cout << membershipFine(feb/29/2016, jan/25/2017) << '\n';
    std::cout << membershipFine(feb/29/2016, feb/24/2017) << '\n';
    std::cout << membershipFine(feb/29/2016, feb/25/2017) << '\n';
}
```

This outputs:

```
join    Date is 2016-02-29
due     Date is 2017-01-25
current Date is 2017-01-24
fine is         $0
0
join    Date is 2016-02-29
due     Date is 2017-01-25
current Date is 2017-01-25
fine is         $15
15
join    Date is 2016-02-29
due     Date is 2017-01-25
current Date is 2017-02-24
fine is         $15
15
join    Date is 2016-02-29
due     Date is 2017-01-25
current Date is 2017-02-25
fine is         $30
30
```

In summary, the use of a library such as this frees you from having to think in terms of `int`s so you can concentrate on the logic you have to implement in terms of dates and calendars.  The result is compact and readable code that is far more likely to be correct.

**Update**

In the comments below the OP asks about how to parse a date from `cin` and how to get the current date.  There are several options.

Here is how I recommend asking for a date:

```
date::year_month_day join;
while (true)
{
    std::cout << "Enter join date as yyyy-mm-dd: ";
    std::cin >> date::parse("%F", join);
    if (!std::cin.fail())
        break;
    std::cin.clear();
    std::string garbage;
    std::getline(std::cin, garbage);
    std::cout << "Please try again.\n";
}
```

If you prefer to ask for some other format, [here is the complete list of parsing flags available for use](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html#from_stream_formatting).

And the OP asks how to get the current date.  There are multiple answers.  If you are content with the current date in UTC, that is the simplest:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace date;
year_month_day today = floor<days>(system_clock::now());
```

If you want the current date in your local time zone, you need to use [`"date/tz.h"`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) ([requires some installation](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation)) and this syntax:

```
year_month_day today{floor<days>(make_zoned(current_zone(),
                                            system_clock::now()).get_local_time())};
```

If you want the current date in some time zone other than your current local time zone, that can be done with:

```
year_month_day today{floor<days>(make_zoned("America/Los_Angeles",
                                            system_clock::now()).get_local_time())};
```

No matter how you parse your `join` and `today`, they can be used like this:

```
std::cout << membershipFine(join, today) << '\n';
```

Comment: I want the user to enter the date the person joined so what type of variable would I store that in? Could I just use int and an if statement to convert the month from numeric to word form? I also used ctime to get the current date so can that work too?

Comment: You could parse `int`s and then convert from `int`s to `year_month_day`, or there is also a `parse` utility you can use to parse directly into a `year_month_day` from `istream` in a wide variety of formats.  `ctime` is a formatter, so I assume you meant `time`, and there is a way to convert from `time_t`, to `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`, and then to `year_month_day`, but I would just use `system_clock::now()` to the get the current time.  That gives you UTC.  If you need local time, there is also a time zone library:  https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html